# Find web element xpath for button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

not able to locate the web element "Next" button, where the Absolute xpath for the button is

```
//*[@id="RULE_KEY"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/button/div/div/div/div
```

Provide the relative xpath, But i tried with the below one which is not working - xpath =

```
"//span[contains(text(),'Next >>')]"
```

Comment: Can you drop the html for the button ? not the full path. thx

Comment: Try the second xpath without the trailing '>>'. There could be a mismatch with the number of spaces. Or even normalize-space(text()).

Comment: What is the HTML? How is someone suppose to help you with the information you have posted?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try following xpath

```
//*[@id="RULE_KEY"]//button//span[contains(text(),'Next >>')]
```